# How would someone hide an SPO library from "Shared Libraries" in OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, onedrive-for-business

I have a document library that I would like to be hidden from OneDrive "Shared Libraries." How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that we cannot hide the SharePoint online libraries by OOB method in OneDrive.

In shared libraries, the frequent list is the top 12 SharePoint online sites determined by the files, news and pages activities.

Comment: :( Thank you. I am noticing my hidden library popping up on Teams when adding a library to a new tab, as well as listed in Flow. Is there a way to hide the folder from other interfaces? Currently, the library is hidden from SharePoint Online UI and Windows Explorer, but I would like it to be hidden from all non-command line interfaces.

Comment: Nope... Only thing you can do is hide it from the SharePoint UI within that particular site.